# Spinner not working in popup window - Android

Tags: android, popup, android-spinner

I have a popup window that asks you to enter some information and then suppose to select a state with a `spinner`. I can place the `spinner` in the `xml` and it shows up fine, but when I try to activate the `spinner` it crashes the app. Here is the code I am using to create the `spinner`,

```
public class DashboardActivity extends ListActivity implements OnItemSelectedListener {
    private TextView state_selection;
    private static final String[] items = {
        "Select State of Driver",
            "Alabama",
            "Alaska",
            "Arizona",
            "Arkansas",
            "California",
            "Colorado",
            "Connecticut",
            "Delaware",
            "District of Columbia",
            "Florida",
            "Georgia",
            "Hawaii",
            "Idaho",
            "Illinois",
            "Indiana",
            "Iowa",
            "Kansas",
            "Kentucky",
            "Louisiana",
            "Maine",
            "Maryland",
            "Massachusetts",
            "Michigan",
            "Minnesota",
            "Mississippi",
            "Missouri",
            "Montana",
            "Nebraska",
            "Nevada",
            "New Hampshire",
            "New Jersey",
            "New Mexico",
            "New York",
            "North Carolina",
            "North Dakota",
            "Ohio",
            "Oklahoma",
            "Oregon",
            "Pennsylvania",
            "Puerto Rico",
            "Rhode Island",
            "South Carolina",
            "South Dakota",
            "Tennessee",
            "Texas",
            "Utah",
            "Vermont",
            "Virginia",
            "Washington",
            "West Virginia",
            "Wisconsin",
            "Wyoming"
    };

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.xmlfile);

        state_selection = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.state_selection);
        Spinner my_spin = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.state_spinner);
        my_spin.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
        ArrayAdapter aa = new ArrayAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, items);
        aa.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        my_spin.setAdapter(aa);
    }

    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView arg0, View arg1, int pos, long arg3) {
        state_selection.setText(items[pos]);
    }

    @Override
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        state_selection.setText("");
    }
}
```

Here is my `Logcat`

```
07-20 13:28:25.535: E/AndroidRuntime(1378): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-20 13:28:25.535: E/AndroidRuntime(1378): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example/com.example.DashboardActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
07-20 13:28:25.535: E/AndroidRuntime(1378):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2194)
07-20 13:28:25.535: E/AndroidRuntime(1378):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2229)
07-20 13:28:25.535: E/AndroidRuntime(1378):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:139)
07-20 13:28:25.535: E/AndroidRuntime(1378):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1261)
07-20 13:28:25.535: E/AndroidRuntime(1378):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
07-20 13:28:25.535: E/AndroidRuntime(1378):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
07-20 13:28:25.535: E/AndroidRuntime(1378):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4945)
07-20 13:28:25.535: E/AndroidRuntime(1378):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-20 13:28:25.535: E/AndroidRuntime(1378):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
07-20 13:28:25.535: E/AndroidRuntime(1378):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
07-20 13:28:25.535: E/AndroidRuntime(1378):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
07-20 13:28:25.535: E/AndroidRuntime(1378):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
07-20 13:28:25.535: E/AndroidRuntime(1378): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
07-20 13:28:25.535: E/AndroidRuntime(1378):     at com.example.DashboardActivity.onCreate(DashboardActivity.java:160)
07-20 13:28:25.535: E/AndroidRuntime(1378):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4531)
07-20 13:28:25.535: E/AndroidRuntime(1378):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1071)
07-20 13:28:25.535: E/AndroidRuntime(1378):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2150)
```

Answer (score 0):

> 07-20 13:28:25.535: E/AndroidRuntime(1378): Caused by:
>   java.lang.NullPointerException

you forgot to add

`setContentView(R.layout.layout_name);` after `super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);`.

Comment: see Line number 160.you have crash at that line.

Comment: Do you think the error may because the my_spin.setOnItemSelectedListener(this); is using 'this'? When the spinner is actually inside the popup layout not the main layout?

Answer (score 0):

**check your**

```
@Override
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
        long arg3) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}
```

Comment: ok than put the code inside this, on which you are performing action after item click !

Comment: @user2544045 your code is accurate are you getting same exception now ?